# How to provide another user to manage Google Cast SDK Developer Console?

Tags: google-cast

Need to provide Google Cast SDK Developer Console to other user to manage this. As the we can't share the root google account credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to share access to another user with out providing the login information which is why it is always recommended to use a common account instead of personal which can be shared with in the team.

We can help you transfer all the applications and devices linked to your account to a new one if you can create one and share us the details using this private forum https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?visit_id=637901837775503161-589961299&hl=en&rd=1

Please reach out to us using the above link for more details.